# Android: How to do a dialog for narrowing a selection

Tags: android

Suppose I want the user to specify his location by selecting a continent from a list, then a country on that continent from a new list, then a state, a city and so on. How would I go about that?

The only way I can think of is to start a new `Activity` everytime the user makes a selection. This has two drawbacks however:

1. I would have to know the nesting depth of possible selections in advance. I would prefer this to be data driven, such that when there is more data to narrow down the selection, this should be presented to the user. For example, some citys may have quarters to be selected, others not. Or can I just recursively recycle the same `Activity`?
2. Once the user made his selection, I want him to be able to go back to where he startet, not have him go through his selection backwards. I guess I could manipulate the back button somehow, but I'd rather not.

Is there a more elegant way for such a dialog then what I've just described? Maybe even an element meant exactely for this?

Note that I'm not interestet in GPS or other location techniques, the continent/city thing is just an example for the kind of dialog I want.

Comment: Take a look at this [blog post](http://cyrilmottier.com/2014/05/20/custom-animations-with-fragments/) by Cyril Mottier. From the conclusion "Fragments and nested Fragments are complex indeed but once you control and master them, you can start enjoying them." Unfortunately for your question, the author is more focused on transition animations and layout topics in general, so not much code to copy-paste, but I wanted to show what is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a custom `DialogFragment` with a [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) inside of it.

Or if the depth of your data is static, why not use a simple form with `Spinner`'s?

Regarding:

> 2. Once the user made his selection, I want him to be able to go back to where he startet, not have him go through his selection backwards. I guess I could manipulate the back button somehow, but I'd rather not.

The `DialogFragment` is your back logic.

Comment: Spinners is not what I'm looking for. ExpandableListView has a fixed depth of 2. I'm looking for something with an unlimited depth.